# Is there a built-in command-line tool under Windows like wget/curl?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, curl, wget

I come from a Linux/Unix background and I have been wondering if Windows has a binary that can download files from the console.

I would like to automate a certain process and one of my requirements it to not install much software, but use the built-in stuff as much as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: to be honest.. wget and curl aren't really built-in commands.

Comment: Windows 8.1, October 2017 - curl and wget are both included in PowerShell, as this shows:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364752/equivalent-of-wget-command-line-for-windows-8-1/46742133#46742133

Comment: I don't have sufficient cred to post an answer on this site yet, but the accepted answer is incorrect. In fact, there is an out-of-box alternative on windows:
`bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal https://path/to/remote/file.txt c:\path\to\local\file.txt`

Comment: UPDATE: As of Windows 10 build 17063 curl has been added to Windows

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no wget like built-in command in Windows. You can use the .net Framework via Windows PowerShell like in this example:

https://superuser.com/questions/362152/native-alternative-to-wget-in-windows-powershell

or like i do and use wget for Windows:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for a native binary, but... what the heck -- wget it is! :D

Comment: The gnu version of wget for windows has a major bug that makes it crash when downloading large files.

Comment: I don't have sufficient cred to post an answer on this site yet, but the accepted answer is incorrect. In fact, there is an out-of-box alternative on windows:
`bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal https://path/to/remote/file.txt c:\path\to\local\file.txt`

Answer (score 33):

### cURL

Windows 10 includes `curl.exe`:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/-/ba-p/382409

so you can do something like this:

```sh
# example 1
curl.exe --output index.html --url https://superuser.com
# example 2
curl.exe -o index.html https://superuser.com
```

If you have older Windows, you can still download it:

https://curl.haxx.se/windows

### PowerShell

```sh
# example 1
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile index.html -Uri https://superuser.com
# example 2
iwr -outf index.html https://superuser.com
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest

Answer (score 28):

Powershell.

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $dest)
```

There's also Invoke-WebRequest in PS 3.0.

Comment: I was really hoping for a native implementation part of the system.

Comment: It is a native part of the system. It comes with Windows out of the box.

Answer (score 8):

I like http-ping utility. You can run with these settings:
ping once and save the contents to google.html

```
http-ping.exe -n 1 http://www.google.com/ -f google.html
```

It does not require installation. [Check more about http-ping here](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/http-ping/)